# cannot find symbol method getDownloadUrl() on Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to show the picture on firebase in my application but this error comes up

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHdyg.png)

Answer (score 0):

In image you it shows you useing

---

`downloadUrl = task.getResult();`

---

use `downloadUrl = task.getDownloadUrl();`

Comment: "task.getDownloadUrl();"   it is not